# $(window).resize() doesn't fire function

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

I wrote a function that's supposed to fire when the page first loads, and when a user resizes the window. It works fine when the page loads, but it doesn't work when the user resizes the window. What's weird is that if I put an alert inside the function, that alert shows up when the window gets resized, but the rest of the function doesn't fire. I'm not seeing any error's in Chrome's console. I've tried changing it to `$(document).resize()`, `$("body").resize()`, and `$(".pricingHeader").resize()`, and nothing's worked. This makes no sense to me.

```
function getTallest() {
    var tallest = 0;
    $(".pricingHeader").not(".features .pricingHeader").each(function(){
       tallest = $(this).height() > tallest?$(this).height():tallest;
    });
    $(".pricingHeader").not(".features .pricingHeader").height(tallest);
    $(".features .pricingHeader").height(tallest + 8);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getTallest();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    getTallest();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what the problem was. I was setting the height of every `.pricingHeader` to a fixed height, which was preventing the tallest from resizing on window resize. Here's the fixed script:

```
function getTallest() {
    var tallest = 0;
    $(".pricingHeader").not(".features .pricingHeader").each(function(){
        $(this).css({height:"auto"});
        tallest = $(this).height() > tallest?$(this).height():tallest;
    });
    $(".pricingHeader").each(function() {
        $(".pricingHeader").not(".features .pricingHeader").height(tallest);
        $(".features .pricingHeader").height(tallest + 8);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getTallest();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    getTallest();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
function getTallest() {
    var tallest = 0;
    $(".pricingHeader").not(".features .pricingHeader").each(function(i, elem){
       if ( $(elem).height() > tallest ) tallest = $(elem).height();
    });
    $(".pricingHeader").height(function() {
        var add = $(this).closest('.features').length ? 8 : 0;
        return tallest+add;
    });
}

$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', getTallest).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: This produces the same issue.

Comment: What are you expecting, does any of the elements change size on resize, otherwise how will you get a different result -> http://jsfiddle.net/9BdgW/ .... ???

Comment: Yes, the elements resize. I think I figured out the issue: I'm setting a height on all `.pricingHeader` elements, which is preventing the anything from getting any taller than initial height. I'm working on a solution.